# package grails.plugins.springsecurity does not exist in jUnit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, grails, junit

I am working on a grails application. In the application views and controllers are only grails components. Instead of using domains and services application have DTOs and BLs java files respectively.

I am writing junit tests in which I required to reauthenticate user using spring security service. But when I run the test it give me the following error:

```
[javac] ... error: package grails.plugins.springsecurity does not exist
[javac] import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
[javac] ... error: package grails.plugins.springsecurity does not exist
[javac] private SpringSecurityService springSecurityService = ...
```

I have no idea why I am getting error even in import. Code:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.SpringSecurityService;
....
SpringSecurityService springSecurityService = ...
...
```

**OR**

Is there any other better way to reauthenticate user in junit test?

I have googled *how to authenticate user in junit test* but does not found any solution working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why this particular issue is happening, but you can't really test security with unit tests. Spring Security is implemented as a filter chain, so you need to create a request and apply the chain.

This could be properly mocked, but it would be a lot of work. Your best bet is to use functional tests, with a real running server and real requests. The risk of false positives with other approaches is way too high.